# bootstrap navbar visible element in between

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

the default bootstrap navbar has only the logo part visible on small screen, and all the right content of the navbar become toggle button. 
Logo  | Menu |  Sign In (right align) (> 767px) 
Logo  |  Toggle Button(right align)(include menu and sign in) (<= 767px)

However, I would like to achieve situation as follow 
Logo | Menu | Icon 1, Icon 2 (right align) | Sign In(right align)  (> 767px) 
Logo | Icon 1, Icon 2 (right align) | Toggle Buton(right align) (include menu and sign in) (<= 767px)

[image]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Menu 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="">Log In <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful or give you some ideas; it takes on some customization but works well.

You can split the `navbar` between `columns` and enclose it with a wrapper.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper .navbar-default {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.wrapper .login {
  display: inline;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  right: 65px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.wrapper .login i {
  padding: 12px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #555;
}
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Login <span class="caret"></span></a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Stuff</a>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
      <!--end nav-->
    </div>
    <!--end col9-->
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="login">
        <a href="#" class="btn"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end col3-->
  </div>
  <!--end row-->
</div>
<!--end wrapper-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">Bootstrap</div>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.</p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.</p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.</p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```css
.icons{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 20px !important;
}
.icons li{
    display: inline-block !important;
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav icons visible-xs">
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Menu 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden-xs"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="hidden-xs"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Log In <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```